# Why does temp->next!=NULL work while temp!=NULL doesn't in Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Why does the following code doesn't work? According to my knowledge, when the temp reaches NULL, (new)ing it should create a new node with temp pointing towards it. Oddly, changing the while condition to temp->next!=NULL works perfectly. Any explanation to this?

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class node{
    int data;
    node *next;
public:
    node(){}
    node(int value):data(value),next(NULL){}
    void addNode(node *head,int value){
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp=new node(value);
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
    void display(node *head){
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    node *head=new node(15);
    head->addNode(head,50);
    head->addNode(head,22);
    head->display(head);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, `node *temp=new node;` is leaking memory.

Comment: You have a memory leak `node *temp=new node;` then you throw away the pointer with `temp=head;`

Comment: what is head? where it is defined?

Comment: @Drop the data doesn't get added to the list

Comment: @Roger why doesn't temp->next produce the same problem? Only way I know to solve memory leak is by deleting temp, but again, wouldn't that delete the node?

Comment: @roni head is defined globally at the time of declaring and defining structure just like the examples I have referred to.

Comment: can you add its definition is it a pointer? is it NULL at start?

Answer (score 2):

you have many mistakes in the pasted code.
if you want to add something to a linked list end like you want here, you first need to find the list end (like you try to do at your code), but you have corner case at start where head is NULL. lets say head is not NULL.

first we find the last node in the list

```
node * tmp = head;
while(tmp->next != NULL){
tmp = tmp->next
}
```

now we have the last node in the list. we allocate new one and fill it

```
tmp->next = new node;
tmp = tmp->next;
tmp->x = data;
tmp->next = NULL;
```

why your loop doesn't stop. might be that head is not intialized and you have a loop in the list (just a place in memory you travel)

adding with head can be null.

```
if(tmp != null){
    while(tmp->next != NULL){
    tmp = tmp->next
    }
    tmp->next = new node;
    tmp = tmp->next;
} else {
    head = tmp = new node;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if not adding the full code confused everyone but I have done exactly that. The only question I have is when adding a new node, why does the tmp->next!=NULL in the while loop condition works while the tmp!=NULL does not? Can you try that in your function where you are adding a new node? Appreciate the response!

Comment: Now I have edited it and put the temp!=NULL instead of temp->next!=NULL condition in the while loop in addNode() function. It doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

`Stackoverflow` is not allowing me to post images..as I'm a new user.XD

[First See this Image](https://s13.postimg.org/r8ip3rnyf/IMG_20160821_040041.jpg)

So, when you completed your loop with:
`while(temp!=NULL)` you end up as shown in diagram.

Now when you enter the code:

> temp=new node(value);
>    temp->next=NULL;

It allocates some memory to temp on heap and is in any way not related to your linked list. So, whenever you use linked list it is advised to allocate to only pointers that consist of your class variables(In this case it is `next`).

After all `temp` is just an temporary variable just pointing to nodes of a linked list and allocating memory to it will not change linked list in anyway.
So, always allocate like using `temp->next`. Not only for allocating but also shifting connections.

This is the reason your code doesn't work in expected way.

Comment: By setting temp=head, temp points to head and temp->next points to head->next right? So, why is it the case that allocating temp->next which is also temporary is not the same as allocating temp? There should be a node created in memory where temp is pointing (NULL) when it is reaches the same as temp->next points (also NULL). Appreciate the response!

Comment: temp->next is in no way temporary(in sense it effects linkedlist). Setting temp=head and changing temp->next will change the linking but allocating a new node in heap to temp will not change the linkedlist.  The thing to note is **`next` is the only variable that connects the linkedlist but nothing else.**

Comment: Oh, ofcourse! I was thinking in terms of variables rather than pointers. Setting temp=head makes the temp point towards whatever head is pointing to, which is in no way temporary and is connected to Linked List. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: BTW, do references in Java work the same way as pointers in C++? I ask this because same is the case when I create a Linked List in Java.

Comment: I don't know java much though.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing a `Queue` as a `linked list` using `pointers`. When you're inserting a new node at the end of your `Queue/linked list` you need to locate the last node of the list so that your `temp` pointer (which you're using to traverse the list) points to the last node of the list and `temp->next` points to `NULL`. Then you can insert the new node by using `temp->next = new node(value);`You don't need the line `temp->next = NULL;` after that because that's already done in the constructor when the new node is created.

If you use the condition `temp!=NULL` then `temp` will traverse the entire list and end up pointing to the `next` of the last node instead of pointing to the last node/element of the list (which is what you need). `temp` won't have any connection with your Queue/linked list. That's why you need the condition

```
while(temp->next!=NULL){
     temp = temp->next;
}
```

in your `addNode` function. I've modified your function below:

```
void addNode(node *head,int value){
     node *temp=head;
     while(temp->next!=NULL){
          temp=temp->next;
     }
     temp->next=new node(value);
}
```